# Firing SPARQL query from an interface

Tags: interface, rdf, sparql, triplestore

I have a RDF triple store, and I want to have an interface in which by clicking a button a SPARQL query will run.

For example, in the interface I have a NAME button and when I click on that button a SPARQL query must be run, and web a page must display which contains the result of that query.

For the interface I want to use JSP or PHP.

Anyone has an Idea or code example how to do that, cause I don't know how to do that!

many thanks for any answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually I'm working on a relevant project on java. I guess you need something like [this](http://test.strabon.di.uoa.gr/NOA/). What you actually want, is string parsing. You can make your interface using either php or jsp. Clicking a button can trigger a specific function that will make the query, and parse the results. There is not something specific that you should do, the whole thing is based on your creativity.

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you give some clarification on String parsing?

Comment: for example in my project (not the one in the link I gave) clicking on a button triggers a function. this function makes http requests to the service in the link, and gathers the results. Then I parse the results and try to present them on a map

Comment: I just noticed your answer. well, string parsing was not the best term to use. generally, the first step is making the query (using methods such relevant to HttpUrlConnection in java). Secondly gather the results (probably in Strings) and finally parse them and present them on your web page. The "difficult" part, is making the query to your database, not parsing the results or presenting them

Comment: Actually want I want is something like your project, by clicking a button a SPARQL query must run and the result must be showed on a web page.

Comment: ok, then try to focus on making the query to your database. the rest is easy! search for method similar to HttpUrlConnection. I guess in jsp you can use this, but in php you have to find something similar. by the way this is not my project, I'm just using this service!